# Validate uniqueness of a field scoped with :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

There are 3 models: `Talk`, `Topic` and `Conference`.
Each have a title and a description.
A `Conference` has many `Topics` and a `Topic` has many talks.

```
class Conference < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :topics
    has_many :talks, through: topics
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :conference
    has_many :talks
end

class Talk < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :topic
    belongs_to :conference, through: :topic
end
```

How do I validate that a `Talk` has unique title within a `Conference`?

The only solution I could come up with is to create another table for the `Talk`-`Topic` association and perform the validation there. But can this be achieved without creating a new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
validate :unique_talk_in_conference
def unique_talk_in_conference
   if self.conference.talks.collect(&:title).include?(self.title)
       errors.add(:title, "Talks should be unique in a conference")
   end
end
```

P.S: I didn't test it